# SourceForge-like site but not SourceForge

Tags: open-source, hosting

This may be off-topic, but I decided to ask it here anyway, because it's very related to programming.

I'm looking for a site which will host a free software project for free, offer SVN and Hg access, bug tracking &co, space for a blog...

Any tips?

Also, should this be community wiki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Kenai which is IMO very nice (especially if you like Jira) and offers Projects, User Profile, Code Hosting, Issue Tracking, Wiki, Forums, Email lists, Downloads, [more...](http://kenai.com/projects/help/pages/KenaiOverview#what_do_i_get).

Below a comparison with the "competition" (seems a bit inaccurate actually, Google Code does offer Hg):

> [alt text http://www.imagebanana.com/img/ikt4ytfr/screenshot_008.png](http://www.imagebanana.com/img/ikt4ytfr/screenshot_008.png)
>
> For more site and feature comparisons,
>   see the Wikipedia page [Comparison of
>   open source software hosting
>   facilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_software_hosting_facilities).

Check it out.

Comment: I think Hg was quite a new addition to google code, so the overview might well predate that.

Comment: Note that Kenai is up in the air at the moment with the Oracle buyout.  Oracle plans to migrate "dev.java.net" to the Kenai codebase, and then migrate all the Kenai projects to "dev.java.net".  Also, just to be a stickler... SourceForge does have online support also.

Answer (score 2):

[google code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/)?

Quotes from their website:

> It provides a fast, reliable, and easy open source hosting service with the following features:
>
> - Instant project creation on any topic
> - Subversion and Mercurial code hosting with 2 gigabyte of storage space and download hosting support with 2 gigabytes of storage space
> - Integrated source code browsing and code review tools to make it easy to view code, review contributions, and maintain a high quality code base
> - An issue tracker and project wiki that are simple, yet flexible and powerful, and can adapt to any development process
> - Starring and update streams that make it easy to keep track of projects and developers that you care about

sounds exactly like your description.

Comment: Just what I was thinking. GoogleCode has a projec twiki, but does it offer a project blog?

Comment: maybe not really a "blog", but it does offer a Wiki and issue tracker with comments, so following development progress should be covered. Plus there are tons of "real" blogging sites out there.